# How to use Serilog to write file for each client?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog

I am making .Net core application and use Serilog for logging. Now I want to use Serilog to write a log for each clients who already logged in.

I expected the application gonna have seperate logger

- Global logger: write server log
- Client loggers: each client gonna have their own logger to write log file.

From what I tried to do the application do generate the txt file. However, it doesn't write anything to it.

**Program.cs**

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder
                    .UseIISIntegration()
                    .UseSerilog((hostingcontext, loggerConfiguration) => loggerConfiguration.ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingcontext.Configuration))
                    .UseStartup<Startup>();
                });

    }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<LoggerManager>();
}
...MORE CODE...
}
```

**LoggerManager.cs**

```
public class LoggerManager
    {
        public static Dictionary<string, ILogger> loggerDict = new Dictionary<string, ILogger>();

public void CreateUserLogger(string username, EnumType userType)
        {
            var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .WriteTo.Async(a => a.File(@$"Log/{userType}/{username}.txt",
                        buffered:true,
                        rollingInterval:RollingInterval.Day,
                        retainedFileCountLimit:90))
                .CreateLogger();
            loggerDict.TryAdd(cheID, logger);
        }

        public void WriteInfoLog (string username, string message)
        {
            loggerDict.TryGetValue(username, out ILogger logger);
            logger.Information(message);
        }


}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
class HomeController {

        private readonly LoggerManager _loggerManager;
        public HomeController(LoggerManager loggerManager)
        {
            _loggerManager = loggerManager;
        }
public IActionResult Index() {

                _loggerManager.WriteInfoLog(authenticatedUser.CHEID, "HELLO HOW ARE U TODAY");
    return View();
}
}
```

appsettings.json

```
 "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "System": "Warning",
        "Microsoft": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Async",
        "Args": {
          "configure": [
            {
              "Name": "File",
              "Args": {
                "path": "Logs/Server/serverlog.txt",
                "rollingInterval": "Day",
                "retainedFileCountLimit": 7,
                "buffered": true
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I randomly found the "sinks-map". This sinks definitely satisfy my requirement.

https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-map